# como criar um slidershow para conteudo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ola pessoal tenho uma duvida vejo que algum sites tem adotado um slide show com imagem e títulos onde depois de um determinado tempo passa para o slide seguinte queria fazer igual o do site do g1 o tecmundo também usa esse alguém saberia por onde começar ou me recomendar algum site .[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O Tecmundo utiliza este plugin:
[carouFredSel](https://github.com/gilbitron/carouFredSel)